# SoapUI - Control flow from groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

In my groovy script I've a loop that I want to execute test step "MyTestStep" to run two times:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    testRunner.runTestStepByName("MyTestStep2")
}
```

Works fine when I run the groovy script - but when I start the test case, the test runner first runs my groovy script and then once again "MyTestStep".

This is not what I want.

Suggestions on how I can run the test step only from groovy-script?

```
--MyTestCase
---TestStep1 GroovyScript that executes teststep2 two times
---TestStep2: MyTestStep containing a rest request
```

So when I press play of MyTestCase: first groovy script starts, which is ok. But then the test continues to execute TestStep2 once more.

Comment: You do it by only running the Groovy step, not the whole test.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: I even tried with testRunner.runTestStepByName("TestStep2"). But when I start my test case, it first executes groovy script and after that test step 2 that is already executed from groovy script. This causes error for my test since iäve assertions in it. See my uppdated question.

Comment: "But when I start my test case". It will work if you run the script itself, not the test case.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question since I figured it out:
Instead of:

```
testRunner.runTestStepByName("MyTestStep2")
```

I used:

```
testRunner.gotoStepByName("MyTestStep2")
```